# C++の配列とbyte型変数の足し算？について

Tags: c++, array

C++言語の初心者なのですが、
とあるソースコードにbyte型の配列にbyte型の変数を足している箇所がありまして、
何をしているのか見当がつきませんでした。
以下、該当の箇所を抜粋します。

```
byte arduino[8];
memset(arduino, 0xFF, sizeof(arduino));
byte uno = something;　//←byte型変数unoには0b000～0b111 (0～7)が入ります。
byte *input = arduino + uno;　//←この行で何をしているのかが分かりません。
```

解説頂ける方がいらっしゃれば良いのですが。

Answer (score 2):

`byte`は標準の型ではないので、整数型だと仮定して説明します。

配列変数を単独で使用すると、その配列の先頭の要素のアドレスを返します。今回の場合、`arduino`とすれば、先頭の要素`arduino[0]`のアドレス、つまり `&arduino[0]`を返します。

これに整数値を足すと、その値だけ配列の要素をスキップした先の要素のアドレスになります。例えば 3を足すと、先頭から 3つスキップした要素`arduino[3]`のアドレス`&arduino[3]`になります。0を足せば、何もスキップしないので`&arduino[0]`です。

今回のコード
`byte *input = arduino + uno;`
で`uno`に 3が入っていた場合、`input`には`&arduino[3]`が入ります。これを後で`*input`とすると、`arduino[3]`としたのと同じ効果が得られます。

Comment: C++17 で `byte` 型が標準に追加されました。 ただし、その `byte` 型は足し算などが出来ない、制限の強い型なので、今回の場合は明らかにそれではないですね。

Comment: なるほど。理解に苦しんでいたので助かりました！誠にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

> byte *input = arduino + uno;

byte *input = &arduino[uno]; ですね。

arduino が配列の先頭アドレスで、そこから、 uno番目のデータアドレス。
unoは、byteで宣言されていますが、int で十分。(byte のメリット無し)
C++ というより、 Cじゃないかと思いますが。

Comment: 簡潔にご説明いただきまして誠にありがとうございます。溜飲が下がってスッキリいたしました。